# MySQL JSON_OBJECT is not resulting into newline delimited json which is needed to write into BigQyery

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

I've a Dataflow pipeline which reads from MySQL and writes into BigQuery. The pipeline is failing and the issue is the format of the data read from MySQL is not NEWLINE DELIMITED JSON.

```
    MySQL rows - using various ways to convert to JSON

1) JSON_OBJECT in Sql query gives below o/p
    [('{"emp_id": "1001", "dept_nm": "marketing"}',), ('{"emp_id": "1002", "dept_nm": "consulting"}',), ('{"emp_id": "1003", "dept_nm": "delivery"}',)]

2) json.dumps(json_object) gives output as {"emp_id": ["1001", "marketing"], "dept_nm": ["1002", "consulting"]} 
    
    BigQuery expects data in the below NEWLINE DELIMITED JSON format - 

    {"emp_id": "1001", "dept_nm": "marketing"}
    {"emp_id": "1002", "dept_nm": "consulting"}
    {"emp_id": "1003", "dept_nm": "delivery"}
```

I'm not sure how to change the format to load into BQ.

Comment: How does the code look like which applies the `json.dumps(..)` and what is the exact input in step 2)? If I apply `json.dumps` to what you are describing in step 1) I get a completely different result

Answer (score 0):

This workaround might be helpful to you.

You can use the [`json.loads`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.loads) function in Python to convert the string representation of JSON into Python dictionaries, and then use [`json.dumps`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.dumps) to serialize them into the required format (NDJSON). The join method is used to concatenate the formatted rows with newline characters in between.

You can then use the resulting **ndjson_data** for loading into BigQuery. Depending on your specific pipeline, you might write this data to a file or use it directly in your pipeline to load into BigQuery.

This is my example code in python:

```
import json

# Example data from MySQL
mysql_rows = [('{"emp_id": "1001", "dept_nm": "marketing"}',),
              ('{"emp_id": "1002", "dept_nm": "consulting"}',),
              ('{"emp_id": "1003", "dept_nm": "delivery"}',)]

# Convert MySQL rows to BigQuery format
bq_rows = [json.loads(row[0]) for row in mysql_rows]

# Serialize each dictionary into NEWLINE DELIMITED JSON format
ndjson_data = '\n'.join([json.dumps(row) for row in bq_rows])

# Print or use ndjson_data for further processing, such as loading into BigQuery
print(ndjson_data)
```